# Is it possible to run safari using docker as a regular browser?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, safari

From the containers I found only this:

`docker pull browsers/safari:15.0`

But I think it will be weak, I did not find a description, but I suspect that it runs there in headless mode.

Maybe someone tried to do it with X11 or flatpack...

I am using ubuntu 22.04 as the base system.

Here is also an interesting tool: https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker

I tried to run it like this:

```bash
docker run -it \
    --rm \
    --name safari \
    -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    browsers/safari:15.0
```

There were other variations, but all of them also failed.